# Angular 2 bootstrap 4.3 Modal will not appear

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

I new to angular so I apologize if this is a dumb question, but I am trying to put a modal in my app.  I took an example off bootstraps website under [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/modal/) and it will not run in my app.  Everything else has been plug and play but for some reason when I click the button nothing appears.

I want to make sure it works before I start customizing it.

'''

```html
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalScrollable">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalScrollable" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalScrollableTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalScrollableTitle">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <h1>test</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good practice to have two frameworks manipulating the DOM, in this case, Angular and Bootstrap JS files. So I Recommend to use a library like [ng-bootstrap](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap), instead of the Bootstrap default JS file or implement the functionality your self. Cause as far as I remember showing or hiding menus and modals in Bootstrap comes down to adding or removing a class to the menu or the modal.

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```html
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalScrollable">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalScrollable" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalScrollableTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalScrollableTitle">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <h1>test</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Neil its working check run code snippet . what exactly do you want to achieve???